# Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object for xls but the same sheet as xlsx works fine

Tags: excel, jet

I have a sheet name "Test (testing)". I can access this sheet just fine when I use a `xlsx` workbook but when the workbook is in the `xls` format I get the following error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E37): The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object ''Test [testing]$'_'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

The error seems to be looking for "Testing [testing]". Is Jet doing some conversion I don't know about? Is there any other reason for this error? Note the workbooks are exactly the same, just the file format is different.

Comment: Did you save it as an xls or did you just change the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

I had to filter out tables ending in `$_` and `$'_` for it to work.

[This](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/excel-prog/115466/The-Microsoft-Jet-database-engine-could-not-find-the-object) post lead me to the fix. `$'_` isn't listed in the post but was causing the issue as well as `$_`.